# Why is TeXForm giving me two different outputs?

Tags: latex

So I am attempting to learn how to use the `TeXForm` expression in Mathematica (as part of teaching myself how to use this programming language), and although it works, when I evaluate the cell, it does get me the LaTeX form of the cell (e.g. `E^(-x)` does return $e^{-x}$), it also returns something else:

```
Out[.]//TeXForm
           \text{df}[[1]]
```

(where the `.` is 2 times minus two the number of the number of expressions I have evaluated. (e.g it's 0 if it's a new notebook as I'm using Wolfram Notebook for this)

which is weird, since I feel like all it should be returning is the LaTeX form of the expression that is being evaluated and not this.

Here's the code that I use (for an example, also 2nd line stays throughout testing):

```
Integrate[Log[E,x],x]
 ( dfn = List @@ ( df // Apart // Expand))[[1]] // TeXForm
```

which returns (since this is the 3rd time that notebook has been used):

---

```
Out[5]= -2x+xLog[x²]

Out[6]//TexForm
           \text{df}[[1]]
```

---

Full code: (was told that it's better to post the complete code so it can be copy/pasted)

---

```
In[5]:= Integrate[Log[E,x],x]
         ( dfn = List @@ ( df // Apart // Expand))[[1]] // TeXForm
Out[5]= -2x+xLog[x²]

Out[6]//TexForm
           \text{df}[[1]]
```

[image]

So my question is: Why does this happen? Shouldn't I only be receiving one output when using `TeXForm`?

Comment: **( dfn = List @@ ( df // Apart // Expand))[[1]] // TeXForm** how is this supposed to do anything if `df` is not even defined anywhere?  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAz9P.png)  it is better to post complete self contained code that one can copy and paste that shows the problem,.

Comment: @Nasser so should I remove the second line entirely and put // TeXForm at the end of the first line or ...?

Comment: yes, if that is what you are trying to convert. Why deal with this `//` stuff any way. Why not keep things simple? Like this   ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyhmZ.png) I like to use one cell at a time. Write one command in one cell. Look the at output, then write new command in new cell.

Comment: @Nasser Ah, so *that's* what I should have done! Thanks!